# Set some php ini params to a specific php file on NGINX vhost

Tags: nginx, php

How can I set some PHP parameters for a single PHP file instead of for an entire directory?

Here is my NGINX config:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index  index.php;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/www;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/share/nginx/www;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, but if anyone has suggestions for improvement.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/share/nginx/www;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 2M \n post_max_size=8M";
}

location = /api/upload.php {
    root           /usr/share/nginx/www;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    client_max_body_size 30m;
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 30M \n post_max_size=31M";
}
```